# Move tool bar in category page to the top in magento2

Tags: magento2, column, toolbar, category-listing

I need to move toolbar section to the column.top, I have used below code in my **catalog_category_view.xml** file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>     
    <move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="columns.top" after="category.cms"/>   
 </body>
 </page>
```

Its not moving throwing error like below,

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSize() on null in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml:18

How to move tool bar to the top section. Because i am looking for tool bar to be in full width rather than into the category product section. Is that can be done. Please anyone help me. Thanks.

Comment: Your magento version ?

Comment: I am using 2.2.4.

Comment: You need to close <page> tag in your xml file

Comment: @cnbandicoot, Yes i have closed it, but not posted here, sorry, updated my question

Comment: did you manage to move it?